# Fail to set up an ejabberd server working with Adium

Tags: ejabberd

I am a beginner for server hosting and I want to implement a multi-user chat room in my iphone/android app. I found xmpp is what I need to implement and for server, ejabberd may be a good choice (because of its scalability and reliability).

I found one article by [Cesare Rocchi](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/) showing how to start up a ejabberd server for testing (I notice my version of ejabberd is 2.1.13 and that on tutorial is 2.1.8 but still give a try) but fail. The author used iChat and Adium to test if the server is working fine after starting up. I follow his step setting up the domain as "localhost" and an admin as "vivi@localhost". On the Access Control List of the web page admin interface of ejabberd, I add a user called "user@localhost". On Adium, I add an xmpp user "user@localhost" with the connect server "localhost" and port number 5222. However, I receive the error "Error: server closed the connection".

I tried input the command "netstat -an | grep LISTEN" to verify that 5222 port is currently listening. When I stop the ejabberd server, Adium's status change to error: unable to connect. It looks like something blocking the connection.

I tried google for the solution for a few days but I could not find out a proper solution. Is there anyone who can suggest possible solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are several points for you to try.  First, ensure you have no, or a low-resolution avatar set.  There's [an outstanding bug related to Adium and ejabberd](https://trac.adium.im/ticket/16552) for this.  Next, start Adium in debug mode (hold Option while starting) so you can get logging output and see what Adium says.

It may also be worthwhile to check the security options for the connection, by default ejabberd will use a self-signed certificate, so strict checking will fail.  I also ran into issues with ejabberd's pubsub feature causing problems with Adium clients and ended up having to disable it.  You can do this by commenting out (`%%`) the `module` directives for pubsub in `ejabberd.cfg`.